# Qt Model / View framework, tree view

Tags: qt, treeview, model-view, qstandarditemmodel

I’m experimenting with Qt and the Model/View framework.
I have some data that I would like to display and edit in a tree view.
I have read the documentation and [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html) tutorial, but I’m still unsure about what is the best practice in my case.
The data comes from a server and looks something like this:

```
int id;
int parentId;
QString name;
float price;
```

The id’s are “running” numbers and all unique so the data might look like this.

```
Id =1
parentId =0 
name= food

id = 5 
parentId =1
name = pizza
```

The id is of no interest to the end user and should not be displayed.

Getting this in to a hierarchy should be pretty straight forward using a recursive function. (But any ideas here are also most welcome)

1. Should I put the data I get from the server straight in to a `QStandardItemModel`?
2. Is there any point in creating my own class and inherit `QStandardItemModel/Item`?
3. Would each field (id, name, price) be it’s own `QStandardItem`?

If yes on #3, When I edit the item that contains a name, how do I get the id connected to that name so I can post the change back to the server.

As you understand these are basics, a sketch of a recommended structure would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use QStandardItemModel.  If you've got an id, then store it the internalId of the QModelIndex and use QAbstractItemModel.